# Grunt watch - bootstrap.less compile error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, gruntjs

I'm using Grunt to compile css on a Bootstrap 3.1.1 project. While watching for changes, I get the following error each time I save a .less file

```
Running "less:compileCore" (less) task
>>SyntaxError: Unable to write "dist/css/bootstrap.css.map" file (Error code: EACCES). in less/bootstrap.less on line null, column 0:
>>1 @import "variables.less";
Warning: Error compiling less/bootstrap.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've updated to the newest version of less and I've tried with multiple versions of node.js.

Comment: And you have the latest grunt-contrib-less?

Comment: I do. This turned out to be a permissions error, and everything worked fine with sudo commands. Thanks for the response @technophobia